# Duda con persistencia de datos en python (ficheros)

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
import pickle,sys

class Persona():
    def __init__(self,nombre):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.pareja = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class Pareja():
    def __init__(self,nombre):
        self.nombre = nombre
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class Controller():
    def __init__(self):
        self.novias = []
        self.novios = []
        self.load_novias()
        self.load_novios()
        #self.load_pareja()

    def guardar_novio(self):
        fichero = open('novios.pckl','wb')
        pickle.dump(self.novios,fichero)
        fichero.close()

    def guardar_novia(self):
        fichero = open('novias.pckl','wb')
        pickle.dump(self.novias,fichero)
        fichero.close()

    def load_novias(self):
        fichero = open('novias.pckl','ab+')
        fichero.seek(0)
        try:
            self.novias = pickle.load(fichero)
        except:
            pass
        finally:
            fichero.close()

    def load_novios(self):
        fichero = open('novios.pckl','ab+')
        fichero.seek(0)
        try:
            self.novios = pickle.load(fichero)
        except:
            pass
        finally:
            fichero.close()

    def load_pareja(self):
        fichero = open('pareja.pckl','ab+')
        fichero.seek(0)
        try:
            self.novios = pickle.load(fichero)
        except:
            pass
        finally:
            fichero.close()

    def agregar_novio(self):
        nombre = input("\nAgrega un nombre\n>>> ").strip()
        novio = persona(nombre)
        self.novios.append(novio)
        self.guardar_novio()

    def agregar_novia(self):
        nombre = input("\nAgrega un nombre\n>>> ").strip()
        novia = pareja(nombre)
        self.novias.append(novia)
        self.guardar_novia()

    def ligar(self):
        novio = input("\nIntroduce tu nombre\n\n>>> ").strip()
        for obj in self.novios:
            if obj.nombre == novio:
                novia = input("\nIntroduce el nombre\n\n>>> ").strip()
                for obj2 in self.novias:
                    if obj2 == novia:
                        obj.pareja.append(obj2)
                        self.guardar_pareja()
                        print(obj.pareja)

    def ver_novio(self):
        for obj in self.novios:
            print(obj)

    def ver_novia(self):
        for obj in self.novias:
            print(obj)

    def menu(self):
        print("""
[1] Agregar novio
[2] Agregar novia
[3] Ligar
[4] Ver novios
[5] Ver novias
[6] Salir""")
        opcion = input("\nEscoge tu opcion\n\n>>> ").strip()
        if opcion == "1":
            self.agregar_novio()
        elif opcion == "2":
            self.agregar_novia()
        elif opcion == "3":
            self.ligar()
        elif opcion == "4":
            self.ver_novio()
        elif opcion == "5":
            self.ver_novia()
        elif opcion == "6":
            sys.exit()
        else:
            print("\nError, vuelve a intentarlo.")
            self.menu()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    init = controller()
    init.menu()
```

1. Cómo hago para guardar las parejas ligadas en un fichero y luego poder mostrar las perejas en un metodo ver_parejas() de la clase controller (teniendo encuenta que se debe aplicar el __str__() a aquella lista con las parejas,pero desde otra clase)?
2. También quiero saber los enlaces entre ellos. Que si carlos esta ligado con karen, si luego se registra un nuevo novio digamos es sergio, y una nueva mujer, digamos es maria,si sergio se liga con maria, entonces la pareja de sergio es maria lógicamente y la de carlos es karen, no quiero que se mezclen o se afecten entre si las parejas de los novios.(es por eso que cree una lista en persona, para que cada novio tenga su respectiva pareja).

Comment: Como sugerencia, las clases deberían estar escritas en mayúsculas para mejor legibilidad del código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero, indicar que la implementación es bastante machista ;-) y políticamente incorrecta pues los novios son del tipo `Persona`, mientras que las novias aparentemente no son personas, sino `Pareja`. Además, no se permiten parejas del mismo sexo. Y lo que es peor, el novio puede tener una lista de novias, pero no a la inversa, ya que la novia es una propiedad del novio... (si bien es cierto que, tal como lo tienes, nada impide que una misma novia aparezca en las listas de parejas de diferentes novios)

Pero centrémonos en el código.

Parece que en tu código vas guardando por separado novios y novias en diferentes ficheros pickle. Las relaciones entre ellos, tal como lo tienes, forman parte de los objetos tipo "Persona", por lo que en el momento que guardes al novio, automáticamente se guardarán también todas sus parejas, por estar en el mismo objeto.

No obstante creo que este no es el enfoque correcto. Ya que la estructura `Controller` tiene su lista de novios y novias (y quizás, si lo reimplementas de forma más correcta pueda tener también otra lista con las relaciones entre ellos, en vez de guardar esa información en cada novio), lo más sencillo sería que guardaras la clase `Controller` y de este modo, automáticamente y por formar parte de ella, se guardarían también todos los novios y novias, es decir, toda la información manejada por tu programa.

Esto tiene la ventaja adicional de simplificar la clase `Controller` al no requerir ya todos esos métodos para guardar y cargar las listas de novios y novias.

Por otro lado, había un error en tu código, en el método `ligar` que buscaba un nombre dado en la lista de novios, pero sin usar el campo `nombre` de cada novio, con lo que en realidad nunca lo encontraría. Además no tienes una función para mostrar las parejas, con lo que no sabemos si se guarda correctamente esta información. He implementado correctamente la búsqueda (haciendo uso de una función auxiliar que busca por el nombre entre una lista de personas o parejas), y he añadido un método para mostrar los emparejamientos.

Finalmente, el programa tal como lo tienes ejecuta el menú una sola vez y luego finaliza, siendo necesario volver a lanzar el programa para poder meter más datos o ver lo que hay. Sería mucho más cómodo que el menú se ejecutara en bucle, hasta que el usuario decida salir.

La siguiente implementación incluye estas mejoras. El programa principal comienza preguntando al usuario si quiere cargar de un fichero o empezar de cero. Después entra en un bucle en el que invoca el menú una y otra vez, hasta que el menú retorne `False` (ahora el menú hace esto, en vez de `exit()`). Cuando se abandone el menu, se guarda el objeto controlador en un pickle, y así se tiene para la próxima vez que se ejecute el programa.

```
import pickle

class Persona():
    def __init__(self,nombre):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.pareja = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class Pareja():
    def __init__(self,nombre):
        self.nombre = nombre
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class Controller():
    def __init__(self):
        self.novias = []
        self.novios = []

    def agregar_novio(self):
        nombre = input("\nAgrega un nombre\n>>> ").strip()
        novio = Persona(nombre)
        self.novios.append(novio)

    def agregar_novia(self):
        nombre = input("\nAgrega un nombre\n>>> ").strip()
        novia = Pareja(nombre)
        self.novias.append(novia)

    def find_persona(self, lista, nombre):
        for persona in lista:
            if persona.nombre == nombre:
                return persona
        return None

    def ligar(self):
        novio = input("\nIntroduce tu nombre\n\n>>> ").strip()
        obj_novio = self.find_persona(self.novios, novio)
        if obj_novio:
            novia = input("\nIntroduce el nombre de ella\n\n>>> ").strip()
            obj_novia = self.find_persona(self.novias, novia)
            if obj_novia:
                obj_novio.pareja.append(obj_novia)
                print("Ok")
            else:
                print("La novia", novia, "no se encuentra")
        else:
            print("El novio", novio, "no se encuentra")


    def ver_novio(self):
        for obj in self.novios:
            print(obj)

    def ver_novia(self):
        for obj in self.novias:
            print(obj)

    def ver_parejas(self):
        for novio in self.novios:
            if novio.pareja:
                print(novio.nombre, "-", ", ".join(p.nombre for p in novio.pareja))

    def menu(self):
        print("""
[1] Agregar novio
[2] Agregar novia
[3] Ligar
[4] Ver novios
[5] Ver novias
[6] Ver parejas
[7] Salir""")
        opcion = input("\nEscoge tu opcion\n\n>>> ").strip()
        if opcion == "1":
            self.agregar_novio()
        elif opcion == "2":
            self.agregar_novia()
        elif opcion == "3":
            self.ligar()
        elif opcion == "4":
            self.ver_novio()
        elif opcion == "5":
            self.ver_novia()
        elif opcion == "6":
            self.ver_parejas()
        elif opcion == "7":
            return False
        else:
            print("\nError, vuelve a intentarlo.")
            self.menu()
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ans = ""
    while ans not in ["C", "R"]:
        ans= input("Cargar fichero o reiniciar? (C/R)")
    if ans == "C":
        init = pickle.load(open("datos.pckl", "rb"))
    else:
        init = Controller()
    while init.menu():
        continue
    pickle.dump(init, open("datos.pckl", "wb"))
```